# Did "restrict background data" *per-app* just disappear in Android 4.2.2 update?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, background-data

Just noticed this now on Android 4.2.2, I'm pretty sure the option to restrict background data per app was there a few days ago.

Now I can't stop the Play Store from using up my data. There is now a global "restrict data access" but it doesn't seem to apply to some apps - like the Play Store.

**EDIT:** weird, now they're back again. I think the only thing I did was log out (via `about:debug`, then Setting -> Debug -> Reset prelogin, the last one)

Answer (score 0):

The option is "Restrict Background Data" and you can access it on Settings -> Power Saving, after choosing a proper power saving mode.

To stop Google Play from hogging your data, open the Google Play app settings and look at the "Auto-update apps" option. There is a possibility to only update when connected to an wifi network.

Comment: the *per-app* Restrict Background Data is in Data Usage, after you touch on an app, at the bottom. The global option is on the menu button of Data Usage. I don't have Settings -> Power Saving, so I think we have different versions (mine is 4.2.2). Anyway, it came back (see my edit), so this is just FYI.